# Shell script: execute cmd on a file, with additional processing of file name

Tags: shell, scripting

So I am going to post a question about shell scripting again.

**Problem Definition:**    For all files under a dir, ex.:

- A_anything.txt, B_anything.txt, ......

I want to execute a script, say 'CMD', on each of them, with the output files named like:

- A_result.txt, B_result.txt, ......

In addition, at the **first line** of these output file, I want to have the **file name** of the original one.

The 'find -exec' util seems to me unable to extract part of the file name.

Does someone know a solution to this problem, by any means(shell, python, find,etc)? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd /directory
for file in *.txt ; do
    newfilename=`echo "$file"|sed 's/\(.\+\)_.*/\1_result.txt/`
    echo "$file" > "$newfilename" 
    your-command $file >> "$newfilename"
done
```

HTH

Comment: +1 despite the niggling that follows.  Arguably, it should be `*.txt` or even `[A-Z]_*.txt` in the `for` line, but that will work if the files are all in a single directory.  The `your-command` line probably needs `"$files"` too.  I would use a singular name `$file` rather than the plural `$files` since at any one time it contains a single file name, not several.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's more than one way to do it (including using Perl, where that's the motto), but probably I'd write it like this:

```
find . -name '[A-Z]_*.txt' -type f -print0 |
    xargs -0 modify_rename.sh
```

And then I'd write the script `modify_rename.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@"
do
    dirname=$(dirname "$file")
    basename=$(basename "$file" .txt)
    leadname=${file%_*}
    outname="$dirname/${leadname}_result.txt"
    # Optionally check for pre-existence of $outname
    {
    # Optionally echo "$basename.txt" instead of "$file"
    echo "$file"
    # Does this invocation of CMD write to standard output?
    # If not, adjust invocation appropriately.
    CMD "$file"
    } > "$outname"
done
```

The advantage of this separation into separate scripting operations is that the rename/modify operation can be checked out separately from the search process - which runs less risk of zapping your entire directory structure with bad commands.

Bash has the tools to avoid invoking `basename` and `dirname` but the notation is moderatly excruciating; I find the clarity of the command names worth having.  I'd be happy if bash implemented them as built-ins.  There are plenty of other ways to get the prefix of the file; this should be safe, though, even in the presence of spaces (tabs, newlines) in file or directory names because of the careful use of double quotes.

Comment: notation wise, once one get used to the syntax, it becomes easy.

Comment: @ghostdog74: and since I learned the basename and dirname notations more than a quarter century ago, they are trivially easy and completely clear to me, and the johnny-come-lately new-fangled notations (which are only 15 years old, but were not available in every shell) are not clear; so, I stick with my preferred dialect, aware that youngsters will likely prefer an alternative dialect, and therefore pointing out TMTWTDI.